# Внутренний оптимизатор Mysql

Tags: mysql, оптимизация

Слышал про существование внутреннего оптимизатора в mysql, в доках ничего такого не нашел.

1. Правда ли что он существует, где можно почитать об этом?
2. В subquery массивный запрос, как правильно его ограничить?

   - select * from table where in (subquery) limit X
   - select * from table where in (subquery limit X)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Правда ли что он существует

Правда, правда. Оптимизатор, он же построитель плана выполнения - собственно и есть основной блок логики сервера. Именно он решает, КАК выполнить запрос.

> где можно почитать об этом?

В официальной документации.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/

> В subquery массивный запрос, как правильно его ограничить?
>
> ```
> select * from table where in (subquery) limit X
> select * from table where in (subquery limit X)
> ```

Это неэквивалентные запросы, и они в общем случае дают разные результаты. Вопрос лишён смысла.